# What is the Physical Distance Between Mos Espa and Mos Eisley?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, tatooine, worldbuilding

Between the two major settlements we see on Tatooine in the Star Wars saga (Mos Espa where Anakin grew up and Mos Eisley where Luke and Ben hitch a ride), how far apart are they geographically?

Days? Just a few hours? We can assume travel by Luke’s landspeeder for speed reference. (Going to pick up power converters)

Canon or Legends is acceptable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the map seen in *[Star Wars: Complete Locations](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Locations)*, the distance (as the crow flies) is **84.6 miles (136.1 km)**.

[image]

Luke's Landspeeder has a top speed of 155 mph, which means that the journey would take less than an hour, even accounting for the need to take a less-than-direct route around the Mesra Plateau.

---

Interestingly, an earlier reference map from the *[*Secrets of Tatooine*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Secrets_of_Tatooine)* sourcebook had Mos Eisley and Mos Espa in much the same position, relative to each other, but the scale indicates that they're 192 miles (309 km) apart.

[image]

Comment: Clearly, Tatooine is shrinking.

Comment: Vader’s been destroying all the sand.  He hates it after all.